# How to Reset Adminer Password?

Tags: database, adminer

Was trying to Change my Database password by adminer. While updating the password suddenly it not working while trying to login. What should do to reset the adminer database password.

Answer (score 1):

Adminer.php has no password: he uses that of the database. The password you need to reset is the password of the database. How to do this depends the sort of database you are using. For MySQL, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html